# Determine how many times dask computed something

Tags: python, dask

### Question

I'm wondering if it is possible with dask (specifically dask arrays) to know if and when something has been computed. I'm thinking of unit tests wanting to know how many times dask computed an array. Similar to mock objects knowing how many times they were called. Does something like this exist already? If not, is there a better way than making a [custom callback](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-local.html#custom-callbacks)? If this doesn't exist, is it something the dask core devs would be interested in adding to core dask for testing?

### Details

Say I have a function which takes in an xarray DataArray, does some stuff to it, and returns it. There are some cases where dask arrays are implicitly converted to numpy arrays including a new dask-user not knowing the best dask-friendly way to do something. I would like to write my unit tests to make sure that I or another contributor doesn't accidentally hurt the performance of a function. This is especially important considering test data is often a simplified/small version of real world cases and the performance hit of computing a dask array multiple times may not be seen in these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to trigger on execution.

One would be to specify a custom scheduler:

```
def my_scheduler(dsk, keys, **kwargs):
    print('computing!')
    return dask.get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)

with dask.config.set(scheduler=my_scheduler):
    ...
```

[Custom callbacks](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-local.html#custom-callbacks), like what you suggest are also pretty easy to implement.

If you're using dask array exclusively then you could look at [array plugins](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#plugins)

There are a variety of other approaches used in the test suite.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing as a simple solution based on [MRocklin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53352314/5446749).

```
class CustomScheduler(object):
    def __init__(self, max_computes=1):
        self.max_computes = max_computes
        self.total_computes = 0

    def __call__(self, dsk, keys, **kwargs):
        self.total_computes += 1
        if self.total_computes > self.max_computes:
            raise RuntimeError("Too many dask computations were scheduled: {}".format(self.total_computes))
        return dask.get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
```

I then use it like this:

```
with dask.config.set(scheduler=CustomScheduler(0)):
    # dask array stuff
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53289286/2) to the question [Determine how many times dask computed something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289286/determine-how-many-times-dask-computed-something) by the OP [djhoese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/433202/djhoese) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>

Comment: Is what you just did some kind of standard practice for stackoverflow? You now have an answer under your user which is my solution based on the accepted answer from MRocklin. Sure you put at the bottom that this came from me and by the license this seems fine, but why do this? I guess it makes it easier to find the answer if people are only looking through answers and not the original question.

Comment: Yes, it's considered "standard practice". See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que. Questions are for questions and answers are for.. answers ^^. It makes it far easier for people to find the correct info when it's in the correct place. Since you had the answer, the correct behavior would have been to create an answer instead of editing the question.  However, if you wish to create the answer yourself, please do it and I will delete "my" answer.

Comment: Interesting. The difference compared to that meta answer and why I saw this as somewhat self-serving is that you posted it as your own user, not as "community wiki". After more reading, I understand what you did and what the comment on the meta answer suggests (you did the work to copy this, you should get reputation for doing that work). I honestly was more curious than anything. I'm fine leaving this as-is.